# Perfect squares between two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many are there natural perfect squares between $31^6-1$ and $42^6+1$? Why?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Answer (score 5):

How many between $1$ and $42^6+1$? How many between $1$ and $31^6-1$? Subtract.

Comment: Very good answer. Since $42^6+1$ and $31^6- 1$ are not squares.

Comment: But $42^6+1$ isn't, because $42^6$ is. And because $42^6$ is a square, there are $42^3$ squares from $1$ to $42^6$ inclusive. Similar considerations apply to $31^6-1$, the number is $31^3-1$.

Comment: How  do I find that how many between 1 and $42^6+1$ or between 1 and $31^6−1$?

Comment: The squares from $1$ to $42^6+1$ are $1^2,2^2,3^2,\dots,(46^3)^2$, so there are $46^3$ of them. A similar argument deals with squares from $1$ to $31^6-1$. There are $31^3$ up to $31^6$, so one less up to $31^6-1$.

Comment: the answer is 15654. But your answer is $42^3-31^3-1=44296$. Why?

Comment: My answer is $42^3-(31^3-1)=42^3-31^3+1$. This is $44298$.

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. I edit your answer to $42^3-31^3+1=44298 .$